# How do I route a request to a specific action in a specific controller in MVC2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my MVC2 application I have an `AccountController` class inherited from `Controller`. I want to achieve the following: when a user tries to open `Account/Payments/NewPayment` `AccountController.ExecuteNewPayment()` method should be invoked.

I added the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    @"CreateNewRuntime",
    @"{langId}/Account/Payments/NewPayment/{whatever}",
    new { langId = @"default", controller = @"Account", action = @"ExecuteNewPayment"});
```

but when I try to request the path above I get HTTP 404 error message with "Requested URL" `/Account/Payments/NewPayment` and when I do that under debugger there's an exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
>   Additional information: The controller for path '/Account/Payments/NewPayment' was not found or does not implement IController.

What am I doing wrong? How do I perform the mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `langid` as part of your route or MVC will not map your URI to it even if you have a default specified.

Take these two routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    @"CreateNewRuntime",
    @"{langId}/Account/Payments/NewPayment/{whatever}",
    new { langId = @"default", controller = @"Account", action = @"ExecuteNewPayment"});


routes.MapRoute(
    @"CreateNewRuntime1",
    @"{langId}/{subLangId}/Account/Payments/NewPayment/{whatever}",
    new { langId = @"default", subLangId= @"test", controller = @"Account", action = @"ExecuteNewPayment1"});
```

If I specify the URI of `/Account/Payments/NewPayment`, which one of the routes should it pick?  If MVC did use the default for `langId` then the first route would always get used since it was declared before the other one.  If you swapped the two then the second one would always get invoked.

When you have varying data in the beginning of your URI's you need to specify them and you cannot use the default value when specifying the route.  In order for these two routes to be hit you would need a URI of `/eng/Account/Payments/NewPayment` and `/eng/e/Account/Payments/NewPayment`

Comment: That's sad. So do I have to specify an extra route so that both `/language/Account/Payments/NewPayment` `/Account/Payments/NewPayment` map to the same controller-action pair or is there a better way?

Comment: @sharptooth - Unfortunately you will need a route for both of those scenrios

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use these routes,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                @"CreateNewRuntime1",
                @"Account/Payments/NewPayment/{whatever}",
                new { langId="en-US",controller = @"Account", action = @"ExecuteNewPayment" });

        routes.MapRoute(
                @"CreateNewRuntime2",
                @"{langId}/Account/Payments/NewPayment/{whatever}",
            new { controller = @"Account", action = @"ExecuteNewPayment" },
            new { langId = "[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}" });
```

Note that here in first route, I am not using langId and setting langId default value to "en-US". In second route langId is necessary but a regex is there so that other routes of your page are not disturbed. Without this regex, langid can be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

`{language}` has no counterpart default value, is `langid` supposed to be `language = @"default"`?

Comment: I changed that, but it didn't help at all. I also have many other routes with such mismatch - they do work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a custom route handler
Have a look at [this](http://blog.jeroenverhulst.be/post/2010/06/14/Extending-MvcRouteHandler-to-enable-localization-of-an-ASPNET-MVC2-application.aspx)

regards.